# UINavigationController & Auto-Layout: RootViewController's view is not shown

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uinavigationcontroller, autolayout

I'm trying to use a navigation controller in my iOS-Project. Here is the setup of my AppDelegate class:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // Generate RootViewController (some auto-layout stuff is going on here)
    MyLayoutDescriptionGeneratorClass *generator = [MyLayoutDescriptionGeneratorClass new];
    MyViewControllerClass *vc = [generator generateViewController];

    self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
    [self.window setRootViewController:self.navController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

The `viewDidLoad` of my view controller looks like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Generate all subviews and their constraints        
    self.view = [MyObjectManagerClass viewForParentViewDescription:_parentViewDescription];
    self.title = @"Hello";
}
```

When I Build & Run the navigation bar is shown and its title is set to `Hello` - unfortunately the view controllers view is not displayed.

If I take out the navigation controller like this

```
[self.window setRootViewController:self.navController];
```

everything works great. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Do you mean if you use `[self.window setRootViewController:vc];`, it works fine?

Comment: without a navigation controller. but the view is shown correctly

Comment: Do you think, that it has to do something with auto layout?

Comment: What happens if you switch off autolayout?

Comment: When I switch off auto layout, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to modify my `viewDidLoad`:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Generate all subviews and their constraints        
    UIView *view = [RuiObjectManager viewForParentViewDescription:_parentViewDescription];
    self.title = @"Hello";

    // Add generated view to self.view and create constraints
    [self.view addSubview:view];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[view]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(@"view", view)]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[view]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(@"view", view)]];
}
```

Comment: Just FYI: The whole purpose of `NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings()` is that you don't have to repeat the variables' names for the keys, so `NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view)` will produce a dictionary `@{ @"view" : view }`